# Keyboard automatically hide whenever tap on text field, what's the matter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm creating a signup page, and **whenever I tap on the text field keyboard is only visible for a sec then automatically hides.** I couldn't understand the problem!    Help me to solve the problem.

I have not added any unfocused nodes.
but getting it. How can give some problem a text Field?
Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:onetap/screens/otp_screen.dart';
import 'package:onetap/screens/signup_controller.dart';

class SignUpFormWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpFormWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(SignUpController());
    final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image(
                image: const AssetImage('assets/images/otElectricianGift.gif'),
                height: size.height * 0.2,
              ),
              const Text(
                'Welcome',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              const Text(
                'Make it work, Make it right, make it fast',
                style: TextStyle(),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Form(
                  key: formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: controller.fullName,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            label: Text('Name'),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline_rounded)),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        width: double.infinity,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: controller.email,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            label: Text('Eamil'),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined)),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        width: double.infinity,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: controller.phoneNo,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            label: Text('Phone Number'),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.numbers_outlined)),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        width: double.infinity,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: controller.password,
                        obscureText: true,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            label: Text('Password'),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock)),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        width: double.infinity,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                SignUpController.instance.phoneAuthentication(
                                    controller.phoneNo.text.trim());
                                Get.to(() => const OTPScreen());
                                // SignUpController.instance.registerUser(
                                //   // controller.email.text.trim(),
                                //   // controller.password.text.trim(),
                                //   controller.phoneNo.text,
                                // );
                              }
                            },
                            child: const Text('Submit')),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                          child: const Text('OR')),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 60,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: OutlinedButton.icon(
                          icon: Image(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/images/google.png'),
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          label: const Text(
                            'Signup With Google',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text.rich(
                          TextSpan(text: "Already have an account?", children: [
                            TextSpan(
                                text: ' SignIn',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                          ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add your minimalist code to replicate the issue.

Comment: Could you please provide code?